# Yii2 REST API Codeception issue

Tags: rest, yii2, codeception, basic-authentication

I am trying to use Codeception to function test my app's RESTful API.  I am using HttpBasicAuth with a custom auth function that validates username and password.

The endpoint I am trying to test is a simple GET /users.  The functional.suite.yml looks like this:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
  enabled: 
    - Filesystem 
    - Yii2 
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
    - tests\codeception\_support\FixtureHelper
  config: 
    Yii2:
        configFile: 'codeception/config/functional.php'
    REST:
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/v1/'
```

My UserApiCept.php starts this way:

```
<?php 
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('test the user REST API');
$I->amHttpAuthenticated('goodname', 'goodpassword');
$I->sendGET('users/1');
```

When I run the suite I get a 401 (Unauthorized HTTP Exception).  In --debug, request headers are empty.  However, when I run the GET in Postman (providing the username and password), the GET returns the JSON response I expect.  So I know the API works.

It appears that there is an issue with amHttpAuthenticated, which I assume is supposed to provide the authorization header, right?

Any advice on how I can troubleshoot this?

Mahalo,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem, I had the dependency wrong:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
  enabled: 
    - Filesystem 
    - Yii2 
    - REST:
        depends: Yii2
...
```

When I initially did the build after adding REST, I got the error message:
"This module depends on Codeception\Lib\InnerBrowser" and then provided an example using

```
depends: PhpBrowser
```

Hope this helps someone.